# what is the difference in output for ps -www and ps command in unix

Tags: bash, unix

What is the difference between unix commands `ps` & `ps -www`, from man pages I saw this statement `-w              Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.`, but when I use the `-www` I don't see any difference in output.

```
-bash-3.2$ ps 18451
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
18451 ?        Ds     1:02 ora_xxxx

-bash-3.2$ ps -www 18451
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
18451 ?        Ds     1:02 ora_xxxx
```

Comment: -w --- WIDE format.. looks like default is wide format so..

Comment: -w , -ww , -wwwwwwwwww all giving same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `-ww` gives you unlimited width, adding more `w`s does not make it longer.

One of my favourites is `ps -efHww`. It shows all processes as a hierarchy along with start time and consumed CPU time, with complete command lines.

Comment: The command `ps -efHww` is really helpful, Thanks a lot Maxim

Answer (score 2):

`wide` in the sense that it doesn't truncate output, not in the sense that it will output extra categories. Try it with `ps -eF` and `ps -ewF` and you will likely see the difference (depending on terminal size). If you instead want to display `full` output with more categories do `ps -f` or `ps -F` instead (or `ps -o` to specify which categories you want displayed)

Comment: `ps -w aux` is a bit odd: it mixes BSD-style options with UNIX-style ones. It is like wearing flip-flops with a suit ).

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin True, just an old habit, edited to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there *is* a difference. You do not see any in your example, since the output is not wide enough. But if you have an output that exceeds a certain width (terminal width), then you will see a difference: the columns are not chopped any more. The result is that the output is wrapped over the line endings.

Comment: True, just start Chrome web-browser - its command lines are long enough to see the difference.